# How to remove null objects of whois results

Tags: string, python-2.7, whois

I use the python-whois module.

I have this code:

```
for whoisInfo in domainWhoisInfo :
     stringWhoisInfo = str(stringWhoisInfo) + str(whoisInfo) + "\n\n"
```

> domainWhoisInfo => array which contains whois data of each domain
>
> stringWhoisInfo => string which concatenate whois data of all domains
>   I concatenate whois results of many domain name in a string.

And When I store these results in a log file I get the
following output :

```
{
  "updated_date": null, 
  "status": null, 
  "name": null, 
  "dnssec": null, 
  "city": null, 
  "expiration_date": null, 
  "zipcode": null, 
  "domain_name": null, 
  "country": null, 
  "whois_server": null, 
  "state": null, 
  "registrar": null, 
  "referral_url": null, 
  "address": null, 
  "name_servers": null, 
  "org": null, 
  "creation_date": null, 
  "emails": null
}

{
  "updated_date": null, 
  "status": [
  "clientDeleteProhibited --     http://www.icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited", 
  "clientTransferProhibited -- http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited", 
  "serverTransferProhibited -- http://www.icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited"
  ], 
  "name": "Panayiotis Yianni", 
  "dnssec": null, 
  "city": "Enfield", 
  "expiration_date": "2017-03-06 23:25:46", 
  "zipcode": "EN3 7FY", 
  "domain_name": "AMON.PRO", 
  "country": "GB", 
  "whois_server": null, 
  "state": "London, City of", 
  "registrar": "OVH (R2367-PRO)", 
  "referral_url": null, 
  "address": null, 
  "name_servers": [
  "DNS200.ANYCAST.ME", 
  "NS200.ANYCAST.ME"
  ], 
  "org": "Amon Interactive Ltd", 
  "creation_date": null, 
  "emails": [
  "panayiotisyianni@live.com", 
  "panayiotis@amon.pro"
  ]
}

{
  "updated_date": null, 
  "status": null, 
  "name": null, 
  "dnssec": null, 
  "city": null, 
  "expiration_date": null, 
  "zipcode": null, 
  "domain_name": null, 
  "country": null, 
  "whois_server": null, 
  "state": null, 
  "registrar": null, 
  "referral_url": null, 
  "address": null, 
  "name_servers": null, 
  "org": null, 
  "creation_date": null, 
  "emails": null
}
```

I am looking for deleting the whois results which are null
from my string.
And get finally only this output :

```
{
  "updated_date": null, 
  "status": [
  "clientDeleteProhibited --     http://www.icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited", 
  "clientTransferProhibited -- http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited", 
  "serverTransferProhibited -- http://www.icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited"
  ], 
  "name": "Panayiotis Yianni", 
  "dnssec": null, 
  "city": "Enfield", 
  "expiration_date": "2017-03-06 23:25:46", 
  "zipcode": "EN3 7FY", 
  "domain_name": "AMON.PRO", 
  "country": "GB", 
  "whois_server": null, 
  "state": "London, City of", 
  "registrar": "OVH (R2367-PRO)", 
  "referral_url": null, 
  "address": null, 
  "name_servers": [
  "DNS200.ANYCAST.ME", 
  "NS200.ANYCAST.ME"
  ], 
  "org": "Amon Interactive Ltd", 
  "creation_date": null, 
  "emails": [
  "panayiotisyianni@live.com", 
  "panayiotis@amon.pro"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: this is PHP ?

I code with python !

Comment: Oops, my bad. However, in a similar way, you can use a list comprehension in Python: `[ whoisData from whoisList if whoisData['name_servers'] is not None ]`.

Comment: please review my question : I have put the code